# How to convert this NOT/AND/OR counter to an all NAND counter?

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, counter, nand

Sequence: 000,010,111,001,100...
Have to build it using a JK Flip Flop for Q0 and 2 D flip flops for Q1 and Q2 and all NAND gates.

Basically I have no problem building this counter with just the normal NOT/AND/OR gates, then I run into problems when I'm trying to convert it to NAND.

J0=Q1
K0=Q2'
D1=Q2'Q0'
D2=Q2'Q1+Q2'Q0

[image]

That's what I have it as, am I doing it wrong for example with the D1 instead of getting the input from Q2' and Q0' I'm getting it from Q2 and Q0? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: hint: why don't you try to build a AND, OR and NOT gate using NAND gates and then substitute these blocks in your circuit and see if there are some simplifications you can do?

Comment: You mean like change the not gate to a nand with the same input? an and gate will then be a nand gate with its input inverted etc?

Comment: yeah something like that. e.g. you can build a NOT gate connecting together both NAND inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Just worrying about interconnect logic.

$$ D2 = Q2' Q1 + Q2' Q0 $$
Take DeMorgan's.  Take Inverse, invert terms and change operator.
$$ D2 = ((Q2' Q1)' • Q2' Q0)' $$

So this is 3 NANDs, no need to change logic, which is what you have done in your drawing.  You are correct.  AND, OR convert to NANDs.

$$D1=Q2'Q0'$$
Here we have a problem. $$Q2'Q0' ≠ (Q2 Q0)'$$

The easiest solution since we already have the AND is to use two NANDs.  Tie both inputs of second NAND to output of 1st or tie one input high.
$$D1= ((Q2'Q0')')' =Q2'Q0'$$

Answer (score 0):

Let us see the first AND ckt o/p logic:
1.1=1, 1.0=0, 0.1=0, 0.0=0
Now the second ckt (nand & Q bar):
0.0=1, 0.1=1, 1.0=1, 1.1=0
V. T. Ingole